# Is using the result of an std::atomic fetch_add to index an array still atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

So I wanted to try implementing a fixed sized, wait free stack with the `fetch_add` and `fetch_sub` atomic instructions. Say that I have a basic stack, with two operations, push and pop.

```
struct WaitFreeStack {
    std::atomic<size_t> cur;
    std::atomic<int>* buf;

    void push(int i) {
        buf[cur.fetch_add(1)].store(i);
    }

    int pop() {
        return buf[cur.fetch_sub(1) - 1].load();
    }
};
```

My question is, are operations in the form of `B[X]`, where B is an array and X is an integer atomic ? In my example for instance, is it possible that after a `fetch_add` call for the `push()` method is executed, and before the `B[X]` is executed, that a whole `pop` and `push` in separate threads could be executed, causing a `push` to overwrite another `push` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B[X]` is not atomic. But if it even would be atomic, it wouldn't help much.

The problem is that you have **expression** **of multiple atomic operations**. Although operations are atomic, the whole expression is not atomic.

Or: an expression containing of multiple atomic operations does not need to be atomic.

The class invariant here should be that `cur` points to the current object in `buf`.
But this invariant is broken between 2 atomic operations `fetch_add` and `store`.

If `B[X]` would be atomic (which is not), one would have following sequence of atomic operations for push:

```
X = cur.fetch_add(1);  // atomic
// 1. dT
ref = B[X];             // let's assume atomic
// 2. dT
ref.store(i);           // atomic
```

For example in the time interval 2.dT imagine second thread popping 2 items and third thread pushing 1 item, all executing before `ref.store(i)`. In this time the value under `ref` reference would change.

Answer (score 1):

> are operations in the form of B[X], where B is an array and X is an integer atomic ?

No.

> In my example for instance, is it possible that after a fetch_add call for the push() method is executed, and before the B[X] is executed, that a whole pop and push in separate threads could be executed, causing a push to overwrite another push ?

Yes.

---

Your example can be equated to:

```
void push(int i) {
    size_t index = cur.fetch_add(1);
    // execution time interval
    buf[index].store(i);
}

int pop() {
    size_t index = cur.fetch_sub(1) - 1;
    // execution time interval
    return buf[index].load();
}
```

There will be an execution time interval at both comment positions above, although the time interval is very very short, but if another thread calls `push` or `pop` and completes the call at this time, it will be absolutely unsafe.

---

The easiest way to implement thread-safe containers is with `std::mutex`, and there are some lock-free implementations (like [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/lockfree/)).